# Nonparametric test for repeated measures

Tags: r, statistics

Is there a non-parametric equivalent to Anova with repeated measurements?

I have two groups and four times (t1, t2, t3, t4). I would like to see the impact of time on my variables according to my two groups (I had calculated the deltas but this does not suit the reviewers). Most of my variables are non-parametric.

One approach I have heard of is that of Friedman which would be an equivalent of the Anova one-way repeated measures, but the implementation does not allow my group factor to be taken into account.

Comment: Hi Barbara, welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow focuses on questions and answers to *specific* **programming** questions. It seems this question focuses on an approach to analysis or data visualization, and thus is not appropriate for SO as defined in the [help/on-topic]. Some such questions may be on topic for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should look into non-parametric versions of linear mixed models.